# Drop down box selectedIndex property

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.fn.fillSelect = function (data) {
    return this.clearSelect().each(function () {
        if (this.tagName == 'SELECT') {
            var dropdownList = this;
            $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                var option = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    dropdownList.add(option);
                } else {
                    dropdownList.add(option, null);
                }
            });
            // code for access "selectedindex" 
        }
    });
};
```

Above is the code snippet for dynamically generating a drop down using jQuery.

I need to set **selectedIndex** property value dynamically for the purpose of showing the saved value earlier. I am going to insert that code into `// code for access "selectedindex"` place inside above code. So how can I set **selectedIndex** property for the `dropdownList`?

Comment: Do you want to set or get the selectedIndex?

Comment: @OllyHodgson set the selectedIndex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the `selectedIndex` property the same as any other.

Assuming that `dropdownList` is a [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement), `dropdownList.selectedIndex = 5;`, should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in this bit of the code:

```
$.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
    var option = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);
    if (/* code to determine if this is the chosen one */) {
        option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    }
    if ($.browser.msie) { /* etc */
```

You're setting the selected attribute on the relevant option.